# 2 Bulb Chandelier not lighting up anymore

Tags: lighting

I have a 2 light bulb chandelier that recently stopped working.  I thought it may be the bulbs so I put in new bulbs.  Still not working.  I then tried resetting the electrical breaker.  Still not working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did it just stop working, or was something done recently that could have caused it to stop working (electrical work, remodel, demolition, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time sockets just go bad.  Though your issue is more likely a lose wire connection probably in the canopy because you did not mention any flicker from the bulbs.

Unfortunately most people have dimmers on chandeliers and dimmers are very sensitive to anything that might go wrong electrically and often go bad.

So on top of a lose wire connection you could also have a bad dimmer, and not totally ruling out bad sockets.

So, something as simple as bulbs not working could very well be quite complicated, and not to mention dangerous depending on if the house is wired with outdated wiring and standards.

Comment: Thanks Kris. So this one isn't a dimmer. I'll try changing the actual light switch under the plate. 

P.s. Nothing has changed prior to it not working.